# Camera::connect() brings AppOps Bad Call: on Android 4.4?

Tags: android-camera

I wrote an apk to test camera on Android 4.2.2 before. This apk works fine.

However, when I moved this apk to Android 4.4.

I got a problem with Camera::connect().

Fail to call Camera::connect() and it prints message:

W/AppOps  ( 1546): Bad call: specified package TestCamera under uid 1000 but it is really -1

I think the reason may be USE_CALLING_UID, security or something that I can't figure out.

Please give me some suggestions, thanks!

My apk is very simple, only one activity. In onCreate(), I called a jni function.

The jni function just do the code belowed:

```
int cameraId = 0;
String16 clientPackageName("TestToGoService");
sp<Camera> camera = Camera::connect(cameraId, clientPackageName, Camera::USE_CALLING_UID);
if (camera == NULL) {
    ALOGE("camera==NULL.");
    return -1;
}
ALOGV("camera=%p.",camera.get());
```

Try:

1. If I put the code above to a executable (main()), then Camera::connect() works OK.
2. I have already add permissons on AndroidManifest.xml

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still of any help. I had the same error in the past. The problem is clientPackageName, that has to be set to the exact package name of your application (which must have the proper camera permissions set on the manifest).